# DataTable DefaultView Filter String with "Convert()"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi I am using `DataTable` and `DevaultView.RowFilter` to display a `DataGridView`.

I have a column with date (`dd/mm/yyyy`).

```
String filter = String.Format(@"account_name LIKE '{0}*' AND type_name='{2}' AND Convert( transaction_date, System.DateTime ) < '{1}' OR is_edited ='true' ", this.accountName, this.dateTimePickerTransactionFrom.Value.ToString(), this.radioButtonDebit.Checked ? "Debit" : "Credit");
transactionsAll.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
DefaultView_ListChanged();
```

It ends up in an error:

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Comment: How does look like this.dateTimePickerTransactionFrom.Value? Can you share?

Comment: Do You mean the problem is at transaction_date ?

Comment: dateTimePickerTransactionFrom.Value is typeOf(DateTime),

Comment: any how I solved it, the table 'transactionsAll' have string data for 'transaction_date' i changed it to DateTime from the database query that fills the table

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,
I solved the problem.
I changed the DB Query from

```
SELECT     transactions.transaction_id, transactions.transaction_amound, CONVERT(char(10), transactions.transaction_date, 103) AS transaction_date, 
                  transaction_type.type_name, transaction_type.description, accounts.account_name, accounts.user_id
FROM         transactions INNER JOIN
                  transaction_type ON transactions.type_id = transaction_type.type_id INNER JOIN
                  accounts ON transactions.account_id = accounts.account_id
WHERE     (accounts.user_id = @UserId)
```

To

```
SELECT     transactions.transaction_id, transactions.transaction_amound, transactions.transaction_date, transaction_type.type_name, 
                  transaction_type.description, accounts.account_name, accounts.user_id
FROM         transactions INNER JOIN
                  transaction_type ON transactions.type_id = transaction_type.type_id INNER JOIN
                  accounts ON transactions.account_id = accounts.account_id
WHERE     (accounts.user_id = @UserId)
```

and

```
    private void ConstraintChanged()
    {
        String filter = String.Format(@"account_name LIKE '{0}*' AND type_name='{2}' " +
                @"AND Convert( transaction_date, System.DateTime ) > '{1}' OR is_edited ='true' ",
            this.accountName,
            this.dateTimePickerTransactionFrom.Value,
            this.radioButtonDebit.Checked ? "Debit" : "Credit");
        transactionsAll.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
        DefaultView_ListChanged();
    }
```